# matplotlib - moving a text annotation

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do I move a text annotation after it's already created? So, for example, after I created a bunch of text annotations in a loop, I'd like to go back and move one of the positions, within the script but not within the loop. In the code below, I'd like to move the 1.9 annotation to above the line. Thanks

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.axes()
x = [0, 1, 1.8, 1.9, 3, 4]
y = [0, 1, 1.8, 1.9, 3, 4]
ax.plot(x,y)

for ii in range(0,len(x)):
     plt.text(x[ii], y[ii]-.15, x[ii], fontsize=25)
```

Comment: Why can't you store the `Text` created in a array and you can update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.axes()
x = [0, 1, 1.8, 1.9, 3, 4]
y = [0, 1, 1.8, 1.9, 3, 4]
ax.plot(x,y)

txt = []
for ii in range(0,len(x)):
    txt.append(plt.text(x[ii], y[ii]-.15, x[ii], fontsize=25))

txt[3].set_x(1.3)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I tried this with `plt.annotate` as creation and `set_x` as moving function. Unfortunately annotation disappers after move(it is visible after creation but disaapers after move). What could be wrong?